# Selection Sorter, but i want the output to merge

Tags: python, selection-sort

So I want to make a sorter, but I want it the output to merge. In my code, I separated the two different type variables from the list, the integer and int.

List:

```
nlist = [19, 5, 'cat', 'rabbit', 2, 32, 'mice', 'dog', 7]
```

Code:

```
def bubble(collection):
    dlist = [e for e in collection if isinstance(e, int)]
    clist = [e for e in collection if not isinstance(e, int)]
    for endnum in range(len(dlist)-1, 0, -1): 
        print(dlist)
        for i in range(endnum):
            if dlist[i] > dlist[i+1]:
                dlist[i], dlist[i+1] = dlist[i+1], dlist[i]
    for endnumm in range(len(clist)-1, 0, -1): 
        print(clist)
        for j in range(endnumm):
            if clist[j] > clist[j+1]:
                clist[j], clist[j+1] = clist[j+1], clist[j]
    answer = dlist + clist
    print(answer)
```

Output:

```
[19, 5, 2, 32, 7]
[5, 2, 19, 7, 32]
[2, 5, 7, 19, 32]
[2, 5, 7, 19, 32]
['cat', 'rabbit', 'mice', 'dog']
['cat', 'mice', 'dog', 'rabbit']
['cat', 'dog', 'mice', 'rabbit']
[2, 5, 7, 19, 32, 'cat', 'dog', 'mice', 'rabbit']
```

Required Output:

```
[19, 5, 'cat', 2, 'rabbit', 32, 'mice', 'dog', 7]
[19, 5, 'cat', 2, 32, 'rabbit', 'mice', 'dog', 7]
[19, 5, 'cat', 2, 32, 'rabbit', 'mice', 7, 'dog']
[19, 5, 2, 'cat', 32, 'rabbit', 'mice', 7, 'dog']
[19, 5, 2, 32, 'cat', 'rabbit', 'mice', 7, 'dog']
[19, 5, 2, 32, 'cat', 'rabbit', 7, 'mice', 'dog']
[19, 5, 2, 32, 'cat', 7, 'rabbit', 'mice', 'dog']
[19, 5, 2, 32, 7, 'cat', 'rabbit', 'mice', 'dog']
[5, 19, 2, 32, 7, 'cat', 'rabbit', 'mice', 'dog']
[5, 2, 19, 32, 7, 'cat', 'rabbit', 'mice', 'dog']
[5, 2, 19, 7, 32, 'cat', 'rabbit', 'mice', 'dog']
[5, 2, 19, 7, 32, 'cat', 'rabbit', 'mice', 'dog']
[2, 5, 19, 7, 32, 'cat', 'rabbit', 'mice', 'dog']
[2, 5, 7, 19, 32, 'cat', 'rabbit', 'mice', 'dog']
[2, 5, 7, 19, 32, 'cat', 'mice', 'rabbit', 'dog']
[2, 5, 7, 19, 32, 'cat', 'mice', 'dog', 'rabbit']
[2, 5, 7, 19, 32, 'cat', 'dog', 'mice', 'rabbit']
```

Is there any way that I can make the output to the required output?

Same dude earlier just fixed some problems and the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The general approach

You can approach this problem by considering that your "greater than" relation is a little more complex than just Python's `>`:

- for two numbers, `>` applies,
- for two strings, `>` applies,
- between any number and any string, the string is "greater than" the number.

Now, implement a function that does that, and use it instead of `>` in your algorithm.

### Implementing that approach

Let's write that logic into function `my_greater_than`:

```
def my_greater_than(a, b):
    """greater than where an int is "smaller" than other things"""
    if isinstance(a, int):
        if isinstance(b, int):
            return a > b
        else:
            return False
    else:
        if isinstance(b, int):
            return True
        else:
            return a > b
```

You'll notice here I took a shortcut: I don't check for `str`, I just check for `int` and assume `str` in the `else` clauses.

That's quite verbose, for clarity, but we can write the same logic more concisely, like this:

```
def my_greater_than(a, b):
    """greater than where an int is "smaller" than other things"""
    if isinstance(a, int):
        return isinstance(b, int) and a > b
    else:
        return isinstance(b, int) or a > b
```

Now, let's use this in place of `>` in your bubble sort code. I'm keeping exactly your bubble sort algorithm, but calling it just once with our greater than function used on the whole list.

```
def bubble(collection):
    my_list = list(collection)
    for endnum in range(len(my_list)-1, 0, -1): 
        print(my_list)
        for i in range(endnum):
            if my_greater_than(my_list[i], my_list[i+1]):
                my_list[i], my_list[i+1] = my_list[i+1], my_list[i]
    print(my_list)
```

And now we can call it on your list to get the output you want:

```
nlist = [19, 5, 'cat', 'rabbit', 2, 32, 'mice', 'dog', 7]
bubble(nlist)
```

prints

```
[19, 5, 'cat', 'rabbit', 2, 32, 'mice', 'dog', 7]
[5, 19, 'cat', 2, 32, 'mice', 'dog', 7, 'rabbit']
[5, 19, 2, 32, 'cat', 'dog', 7, 'mice', 'rabbit']
[5, 2, 19, 32, 'cat', 7, 'dog', 'mice', 'rabbit']
[2, 5, 19, 32, 7, 'cat', 'dog', 'mice', 'rabbit']
[2, 5, 19, 7, 32, 'cat', 'dog', 'mice', 'rabbit']
[2, 5, 7, 19, 32, 'cat', 'dog', 'mice', 'rabbit']
[2, 5, 7, 19, 32, 'cat', 'dog', 'mice', 'rabbit']
[2, 5, 7, 19, 32, 'cat', 'dog', 'mice', 'rabbit']
```

### Additional notes

- You might notice I took a copy of `collection` into `my_list` on the first line of `bubble()`. That's because I don't want to modify the input list I was provided. If we worked directly on `collection`, we would find `nlist` also sorted after calling `bubble()`.
- The other reason to copy the collection with a call to `list()` is that it lets us accept anything iterable. Collections could be a set, a list, a tuple, a dictionary or any other iterable in Python, and our sort function would work on it anyway.
- I print the output because that's what you did, but I would normally have had a return statement in there: replace `print(my_list)` on the last line of `bubble()` by `return my_list`.

Comment: Can you help me on what to do, to do that?

Comment: Well, yes, I could, but I now I have to ask: is this a programming assignment? It's clearly a learning exercise, anyway, and as such I think I have provided the key insight you need to proceed, and you'll get more out of the exercise if you solve the next step yourself.

Comment: a not graded exercise, that's why i have very little knowledge on what to do next

Comment: OK, I'll byte. Edit forthcoming.